# Could not process parameters tkinter and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from MySQL table and showing the result in Tkinter label

```
    sql=("SELECT fname,lname,ID from students_details where fname = %s")  
    val=(name)
    mycursor.execute(sql,val)
    results = mycursor.fetchall()
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()

    l2=Label(top3, text = '{}Your attendance has been recorded'.format(results),font=("Helvetica", 14),bg='#BFD5ED')
    l2.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.10,anchor =S)
```

The error i got is`Could not process parameters`

Any ideas or suggestions will be helpful!!

Comment: Post the full traceback as it contains which line causing the problem.  Also no need to call commit() for SELECT statement.  Your code seems to expect at most one record returned, so better use fetchone() instead.

Comment: Try changing `val=(name)` to `val=(name,)`.